# Dynamically create an array of TYPE in C

Tags: c, arrays, types, dynamic

I've seen many posts for c++/java, but nothing for C. Is it possible to allocate memory for an array of type X dynamically during run time? For example, in pseudo,

```
switch(data_type) 
     case1:float, create a new array of floats to use in the rest of the program
     case2:int, create new array of ints to use in the rest of the program
     case3:unsigned, ....
     // etc.
```

In my program I determine the data type from a text header file during run time, and then I need to create an appropriate array to store/manipulate data. Is there some kind of generic type in C?

EDIT: I need to dynamically create and DECIDE which array should be created.

Thanks,
csand

Comment: I apologize for the formatting of the question; something went wrong there.

Comment: There is no need to cast malloc, nor the implicit conversions from/to `void*`.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you calculate the total size, in bytes, required from the array, you can just allocate that much memory and assign it to the correct pointer type.

Ex:

```
void * data_ptr = malloc( data_sz );
```

then you can assign it to a pointer for whatever type you want:

```
int *array1 = (int *)data_ptr;
```

or

```
float *array2 = (float *)data_ptr;
```

NOTE: malloc allocates memory on the heap, so it will not be automatically freed. Make sure you free the memory you allocate at some point.

**UPDATE**

```
enum {
    DATA_TYPE_INT,
    DATA_TYPE_FLOAT,
    ...
};

typedef struct {
    int data_type;
    union {
        float * float_ptr;
        int * int_ptr;
        ...
    } data_ptr;
} data;
```

While this might allow you to store the pointer and tell what type of pointer you should be using, it still leaves the problem of not having to branch the behavior depending on the data type. That will be difficult because the compiler has to know the data type for assignments etc.

Comment: Void *, totally forgot about. I think this will solve my issue. Cheers to everyone who replied.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help me. My problem still resides with the decision/scope of the variable. It is true that I could use void* and then cast a new array. However, how would my program know which array to use? After declaring "int *array1" or "float *array2" I need my program to use that array. Declaring array1 and array2 inside a switch or if block leaves my scope encapsulated there. What I need is: Declare generic array space -> decide data type - use array of appropriate data type.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid textually having 8 different blocks of the exact same code, except they have a different array type for each one.

Comment: @csand: Well that will be an issue because whatever the right hand value is will also depend on the type used. In terms of the pointer itself you could use a struct with a type flag and a union of the different pointer types.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with unions (and am currently reading some man pages), but can you explain what you mean by type flags?

Comment: @csand: since you are declaring your array with different type of data I suppose you will do *different* operation on that array based on the data type?

Comment: No the operations are the same. I'm reading in hyperspectral pixel data and running some calculations on it. Every image can be a different format though and reading in the binary data is sensitive to that.

Comment: @csand I updated the answer with a quick example of what I mean. Doing calculations without knowing the data type is going to pose an issue in C though. You can't generate the assembly code for those sorts of calculations without knowing the type at compile time.

Comment: Thanks @ghills, and everyone else. I will try unions and see how far I can get.

Comment: Note that when using this method that the size of the allocated memory remains constant from data type to data type -- not the number of elements (a 32 byte array would hold 32 `char` s or 8 `int` s or 4 `double` s [assuming 32 bit system where a `char` is 8 bits, `int` 32 bits and `double` 64.])

Comment: Yes, that is why I specified it must be the total size, in bytes. Not the number of elements. It is easy enough to figure out of course, but it is an important distinction.

Comment: @csand: The simplest way to solve that would be to pick one format as the one to do the calculations in, then convert other inputs to that format.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a hard time doing this in C because C is statically typed and has no run-time type information.  Every line of C code has to know exactly what type it is dealing with.

However, C comes with a nifty and much-abused macro preprocessor that lets you (among other things) define new functions that differ only in the static type.  For example:

```
#define FOO_FUNCTION(t) t foo_function_##t(t a, t b) { return a + b; }

FOO_FUNCTION(int)
FOO_FUNCTION(float)
```

This gets you 2 functions, foo_function_int and foo_function_float, which are identical other than the name and type signature.  If you're not familiar with the C preprocessor, be warned it has all sorts of fun gotchas, so read up on it before embarking on rewriting chunks of your program as macros.

Without knowing what your program looks like, I don't know how feasible this approach will be for you, but often the macro preprocessor can help you pretend that you're using a language that supports generic programming.